# What does the [decision] tag mean?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The [decision](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision) tag currently has eight questions thus tagged, covering a wide range of topics.

Their only common thread among them seems to be that they are somehow about someone trying to make a decision about something finance-related.

However, any question based on a real-world problem and is on topic on Personal Finance & Money SE would hopefully meet that criteria.

**Do we want that tag? What should it actually mean? Or is the site better off getting rid of that tag?**

Comment: agreed. I'll wait to see other comments or answers before acting. Don't want to unilaterally just kill the tag.

Comment: do we have a [tag:burninate] tag on meta?

Answer (score 7):

I don't think this tag is useful as it's too vague and won't be useful for anyone looking for similar questions. It should be deleted.

**Update:** I've now removed it from all existing questions. That doesn't stop someone using it again, but they'll need enough reputation to create a tag.